# It is possible convert srt file to vtt then append video

Tags: javascript, html

Video files generally work on vtt files So I want it to convert the file to vtt first, then put it dynamic into video I have two different files One of them converts VTT files to video but not able to receive srt file It can accept both files at the same time, via the input file The second converts the srt file to vtt but does not convert it to video

first, my code appended vtt file to the video I went to convert srt to vtt after that append it to the video.

```js
        function convert() {
          var input = document.getElementById("srt");
          var output = document.getElementById("webvtt");
          var srt = input.value;
          var webvtt = srt2webvtt(srt);
          output.innerHTML = "<textarea rows=20 cols=80>"
                             + webvtt +
                             "</textarea>";
        }

        function srt2webvtt(data) {
          // remove dos newlines
          var srt = data.replace(/\r+/g, '');
          // trim white space start and end
          srt = srt.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

          // get cues
          var cuelist = srt.split('\n\n');
          var result = "";

          if (cuelist.length > 0) {
            result += "WEBVTT\n\n";
            for (var i = 0; i < cuelist.length; i=i+1) {
              result += convertSrtCue(cuelist[i]);
            }
          }

          return result;
        }

        function convertSrtCue(caption) {
          // remove all html tags for security reasons
          //srt = srt.replace(/<[a-zA-Z\/][^>]*>/g, '');

          var cue = "";
          var s = caption.split(/\n/);

          // concatenate muilt-line string separated in array into one
          while (s.length > 3) {
              for (var i = 3; i < s.length; i++) {
                  s[2] += "\n" + s[i]
              }
              s.splice(3, s.length - 3);
          }

          var line = 0;

          // detect identifier
          if (!s[0].match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/) && s[1].match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/)) {
            cue += s[0].match(/\w+/) + "\n";
            line += 1;
          }

          // get time strings
          if (s[line].match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/)) {
            // convert time string
            var m = s[1].match(/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?\s*--?>\s*(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?/);
            if (m) {
              cue += m[1]+":"+m[2]+":"+m[3]+"."+m[4]+" --> "
                    +m[5]+":"+m[6]+":"+m[7]+"."+m[8]+"\n";
              line += 1;
            } else {
              // Unrecognized timestring
              return "";
            }
          } else {
            // file format error or comment lines
            return "";
          }

          // get cue text
          if (s[line]) {
            cue += s[line] + "\n\n";
          }

          return cue;
        }
   let input = document.querySelector('input')

let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')

// This event listener has been implemented to identify a
// Change in the input section of the html code
// It will be triggered when a file is chosen.
input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    let files = input.files;

    if (files.length == 0) return;

    /* If any further modifications have to be made on the
    Extracted text. The text can be accessed using the
    file variable. But since this is const, it is a read
    only variable, hence immutable. To make any changes,
    changing const to var, here and In the reader.onload
    function would be advisible */
    const file = files[0];

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.result;

        // This is a regular expression to identify carriage
        // Returns and line breaks
        const lines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        textarea.value = lines.join('\n');

    };

    reader.onerror = (e) => alert(e.target.error.name);

    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    input {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    textarea {
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 70%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Text file reading</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    input {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    textarea {
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 70%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1 style="color: green;">
        convert srt to vtt
        </h1>
        <div>
            <input type="file">
            <textarea cols="30" rows="20" id="srt" hidden="hidden" 
                    placeholder="text will appear here">
            </textarea>
<button onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
 <div id="webvtt"></div>

        </div>
    </center>


    

</body>

</html>
```